# Cypress screenshot comparison with image-snapshot vs plugin-snapshot dependency

Tags: cypress

To compare screenshots, we can use either cypress-image-snapshot or cypress-plugin-snapshot.

Are there any differences between these plugins in terms of comparing images please ?.  I searched , couldn't find exact reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a quick look at the npm dependencies of both you can see what image processing dependency they use, and as far as I can tell it's [jest-image-snapshot](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-image-snapshot) for `cypress-image-snapshot` and [pixelmatch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pixelmatch) for `cypress-plugin-snapshots`. You can then decide which one looks better by number of dependents/downloads/versions if you lack better technical knowledge like I do.

On another hand, I decided for `cypress-visual-regression` in the end as `cypress-image-snapshot` shows some "resolve dependency tree" errors with latest cypress versions, and `cypress-plugin-snapshots` still has some "Caveats" listed in their description, plus they're not often updated.